# why my view controller not call the - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method？

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, viewdidappear

I want to do something in the viewDidAppear method but this method not auto calling the SDK
describe this method is Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a window. if means implement this method in my view controller can auto calling?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    ...
}
```

Comment: i think its better to try to explain. he looks like a new user. it took me sometime before i understood the ranking system. so- user 327661, when you receive an answer to your question you should mark the good answer as accepted by clicking the green mark on the left of the question. it will improve your chances to get answers in the future. and for your question - can you show some code, it will be helpful.

Comment: Please add code describing how you add the view and we can probably help you. right now, it's impossible to know why and what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you add your view to the view hierarchy. If you push your controller on an navigation stack for example, this method will be called automatically. If however you add the view 'manually', for example using `addSubview:` then you yourself are responsible for calling this method on the controller.